# Function Attributes - Scope

Tags: python, function, scope, attributes, decorator

So I have this code:

```
def collect_input(func):
    """
    A decorator which adds an all_input attribute to the wrapped function.
    This attribute collects any input passed to the function.
    """
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapper.all_input.append(*args)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    wrapper.all_input = []
    return wrapper

@collect_input
def foo(bar):
    print('in foo')

foo(5)
foo('spam')

print(foo.all_input)
```

My question is: Why can you access `foo.all_input`, if it is declared in the `collect_input` scope?

Comment: Actually, you're not accessing `foo.all_input` but `wrapper.all_input` because you've wrapped your function with a decorator which returns the `wrapper` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nice thing of Python is that it has a set of rules to trate its objects, and very little exceptions to these rules.

In this case, the function that is decorated is just a normal Python object. One that happens to be also callable.

What happens in the line `wrapper.all_input = []` inside collect_input is that it sets an attribute on the object - at that point named `wrapper` - but which is the  object that will be returned and take the place of the `foo` function in the global scope. That is the how decorators work.

So lets got  trough it step by step to make it as clear as possible:

1. When running the code above, it defines the `collect_input` function - which is designed to be used as a decorator.
2. Then it defines `foo` function, but before it is added to the global scope, it is passed into the `collect_input` function. That is what the "@" syntax does. Prior to its existence, the way to decorate functions as to first define a function, and then, replace it for the decorator's return value with a normal assignment. So, the code above is the same as:

   def foo(...):
       ...

   foo = collect_input(foo)
3. Inside "collect_input", the original `foo` func will be called inside the new `wrapper` function. This `wrapper` function: a new (function) object created each time the decorator `collect_input` is called is the object that will take the place of the outermost `foo` definition. You can see that inside the code for `wrapper` there is extra code to do exactly what the `collect_input` is meant to: annotate the input parameters in a list, attached to itself and then resume the call to the original function - `foo` in this case.
4. Finally the `wrapper` object that is returned by `collect_input` takes the place of `foo`, but has the `all_inputs` list attached to it inside the decorator call. So it can be accessed in the global scope as an attribute of the `foo` object - regardless of where it was defined. Note that you can't, outside the function, use the names `func` or `wrapper`, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
@collect_input
def foo(bar):
    print(foo.__name__) # wrapper
    print('in foo')
```

you can see how `wrapper` takes places of `foo`